# DownloadString with basic auth similar to psget's

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Anyone know how I can modify the DownloadString below so I can pass basic auth credentials as well?

I am using the same technique used for PsGet (http://psget.net/) to download my own internal scripts and execute them on the fly. However my server is secured using basic auth. I am having trouble applying the credentials and still executing the line using Invoke-Expression.

I need it in one line as I am executing it using "powershell.exe -Command..."

(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in one line (well, unless you wrap it up as a cmdlet), but it is easy enough to supply the required credentials:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential "user","pass"
$wc.DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
```

Comment: Mmm unfortunately I need it in one line as I want to execute it using powershell.exe remotely and I'm not able to easily transfer a cmdlet. I'll have to find another way. Thanks

Comment: You can string multiple commands on a single line by using the semicolon: "$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true ; wc.DownloadString('')"

Comment: @NabilS you may check ScriptBlock argument, it allows sending multiple lines of script

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the authorization header on the WebClient:

```
$wc = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$cred = 'bob:password'
$enc_cred = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($cred))
$wc.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic $enc_cred")
$wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:81/") | Invoke-Expression
```

Note - the credential string in base64 is not encrypted.

Comment: Am I able to pass the above as inlet long string to the -command argument of powershell.exe. I have tried with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After digging, here is a one liner:

```
Invoke-Expression((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://example.com/example.ps1' -Authentication Basic -Credential (Get-Credential)))
```

The command has been run, will prompt for username and password.

It's also possible to automatically set the username with an arbitrary value:

```
Invoke-Expression((Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://example.com/example.ps1' -Authentication Basic -Credential (Get-Credential  -Credential $Env:UserName)))
```

(Tested on powershell core 7)